# Limiting decimals of all values in my list

Tags: netlogo

How can I round all numbers within my list? The primitive `precision` only allows to do so for numbers but not for lists. Is there a possibility to limit the number of decimals of (either all numbers in the model) (or) all the numbers in my list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map will do what you need. Here's a code snippet to play with

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let mylist [ 1.333333444 1.4443 3.886666 1.999]
  show mylist
  set mylist map [ x -> precision x 2 ] mylist
  show mylist
  reset-ticks
end
```